# Invoke gdb from python script

Tags: python, gdb

where should my python files be stored so that I can run that using gdb. I have custom gdb located at /usr/local/myproject/bin. I start my gdb session by calling ./arm-none-eabi-gdb from the above location.

I don't know how this gdb and python are integrated into each other.

Can anyone help.?

Comment: They aren't integrated into each other. You can do `import os; os.system("./arm-none-eabi-gdb")`

Comment: I want to establish interactive session so that I can execute my python script and within python script I want to call gdb commands and record the output. I want to do import gdb in my python script

Comment: @ForceBru `They aren't integrated into each other.` Wrong answer. They are integrated quite well They are integrated into each other. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use Python subprocess module - you could start GDB from python and drive GDB from python, passing commands on-the-fly

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: I want to establish interactive session so that I can execute my python script and within python script I want to call gdb commands and record the output. I want to do import gdb in my python script

Comment: @user2118095 you might want to take a look at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out. What I understood is

GDB embeds the Python interpreter so it can use Python as an extension language.

You can't just import gdb from /usr/bin/python like it's an ordinary Python library because GDB isn't structured as a library.

What you can do is source MY-SCRIPT.py from within gdb (equivalent to running gdb -x MY-SCRIPT.py).